# Installing jenkins on ec2 instance is successful but login issues for jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have installed `jenkins` on `ec2` instance and it was successful.When I try to enter the url,`(ec2-instance):8080` where `jenkins` homepage will be opened.It asks for username and password.I have setup the password for jenkins for the user(me) and restarted `jenkins` on `ec2`. When I try to login with the right username, password still it leads to failure and it does not show anything on logs to verify something went wrong.If anyone can help with this question or any suggestions that would be truly appreciated.